# Swift dropbox progress bar

Tags: swift, dropbox-api

I'm working on an swift app that uploads images to a dropbox client 
the up lode process works fine i just want to display the the progress of the upload

thank you for you help

```
  func uplodeimage(filePath : String , fileData : NSData)
{

        let client = Dropbox.authorizedClient ;

        client?.filesUpload(path: filePath, body: fileData).progress({ (bytesWritten : Int64, totalBytesWritten : Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite : Int64) -> Void in


        let uplodProgress : Float  = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite) as Float;


 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

    self.progressbar.progress = uplodProgress
    self.progressLabil.text = "\(uplodProgress * 100)%"
    self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating();
    self.loadingIndicator.removeFromSuperview();
    self.loginBtn.enabled = true ;
    self.uplodBtn.enabled = true;

            });




        });


}
```

not that the client upload progress is a dropbox function

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i want the progress bar to update

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    self.progressBar.setProgress(Float(totalBytesWritten)/Float(totalBytesExpected), animated: true)
});
```